# How to plot the tangent and its projection on xy-plane

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to plot the tangent and its projection on xy-plane. I want to actually reproduce the surface as shown below.
[image]
Please modify my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
        declare function={f(\x,\y)=2-.8*pow(\x-1.25,3)-0.8*pow(\y-1,3);}]
        \begin{axis}[view={125}{30},colormap/blackwhite,axis lines=middle,%
            zmax=2.2,zmin=0,xmin=0,xmax=2.4,ymin=0,ymax=2,%
            xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,
            xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty]
            %surface 
            \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=0.6:2,domain y=0.5:1.2,opacity=0.4] {f(x,y)};
            %curve on surface
            \addplot3[thick,domain=0.4:1.2,samples y=1]  ({x+.6},{1.5*x},{f(x+.6,1.5*x)}); 
            \draw[dashed] (1,0,0) node[above left]{$x_0$} -- (1.1,1.2,0) node[bullet] (b1) {}  -- (0,1.2,0) node[above right]{$y_0$} (1.1,1.2,0) -- (1.1,1.2,{f(1,1.2)-.42})node[bullet] {};
                \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=0.6:2,domain y=1.2:1.9,opacity=0.4] {f(x,y)};
                \draw (1,1,{f(1,1.2)}) -- (1,0.2,{f(1,1.2)+0.2}) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux2);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For a sphere, the tangent will be perpendicual to the radius.  For an ellipsoid, the tangent wil be perpendicular to the bisector of the two lines to the foci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I slightly modified your code and added constants that control the point and the curve, and the partial derivatives of the function.  In this way you can define the tangent vector consistently; it is `(\ux,\uy,\uz)` in the code below.

Don't forget, the order of the graphical elements counts.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
  declare function={%
    f(\x,\y)=2-.8*pow(\x-1.25,3)-0.8*pow(\y-1,3);
    fx(\x,\y)=-.8*3*pow(\x-1.25,2);
    fy(\x,\y)=-.8*3*pow(\y-1,2);
  },
  evaluate={%
    real \a, \b, \ux, \uy, \uz, \t;
    \ux = 1;
    \uy = 1.5;
    \t = .8;
    \a = \ux*\t +.6;
    \b = \uy*\t;
    \uz = fx(\a,\b)*\ux +fy(\a,\b)*\uy;
  }]
  \begin{axis}[%
    view={125}{30},
    colormap/blackwhite,
    axis lines=middle,
    zmax=2.2, zmin=0,
    xmin=0, xmax=2.4,
    ymin=0, ymax=2,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty]
    % point
    \draw[blue, dashed] (\a,0,0) node[below] {$x_0$}
    -- (\a,\b,0) node[bullet] (pxy) {}
    -- (0,\b,0) node[below] {$y_0$};
    \draw[blue, dashed] (pxy.center)
    -- (\a,\b,{f(\a,\b)}) node (p) {};
    % surface 
    \addplot3[%
    surf,
    shader=interp,
    domain=0.6:2,
    domain y=0.5:1.9,
    opacity=0.3] {f(x,y)};
    
    % curve on surface
    \addplot3[
    thick,
    domain=0.4:1.2,
    samples y=1]  ({\ux*x+.6}, {\uy*x}, {f(\ux*x+.6,\uy*x)});

    % curve projection
    \addplot3[
    thick,
    domain=0.4:1.2,
    samples y=1]  ({x+.6}, {1.5*x}, 0);

    \draw[blue] (p) node[bullet] {};

    %tangent vector
    \draw[blue, very thick, -Latex] (p.center)
    -- ++(\ux,\uy,\uz) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux2);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```